# How do I get the updated look in LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice

Running LibreOffice 5.4, but my GUI looks really dated

[image]

But I've seen a more updated and modern version of the GUI

[image]

So how do I get mine to look like the second picture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open LibreOffice, go to *Tools > Options > Advanced* (or press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f12</kbd> and then select *Advanced*), check *Enable experimental features (may be unstable)* and select *OK*.

[image]

The option to select different toolbar layouts (from *View > Toolbar Layout*, just as in the attached gif) should appear in all LibreOffice applications (Writer, Calc etc.) now.

On top of that if you want the icons to be the same as the ones in the gif, you may go to *Tools > Options > View* (or press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f12</kbd> and then select *View*), select *Breeze* in the box next to "*Icon style:*" and click on *OK*.

[image]

Comment: I wasn't necessarily talking about the tabbed toolbar, but the actual overall look of them. The icons, the color, etc. It just looks more minimalistic and cleaner overall. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @Tony There is a way to change icon theme in LibreOffice, but I'm not sure which icon pack can be make it look like the one in the animation. My one with Papirus looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3t93.png). Please ask a separate question for that. Also I think this question is really wrongly worded then. I believe anyone would see the phrase "*more updated and modern version of the GUI*" the animation you provided and will think of the tabbed toolbar.